# Is there a way fully traverse a python dictionary that has unpredictable length but predictable structure?

Tags: python

Consider the following dictionary:

```
{
    "Key1":"value1",
    "Key2": []
}
```

Accessing the value for Key1 is trivial: `dict_name['Key1']`. Now consider it with one more level:

```
{
    "Key1":"valueA",
    "Key2": [
        {
            "Key1":"valueB",
            "Key2":[]
        },
        {
            "Key1":"valueC",
            "Key2":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to get a list of all Key1 values. So for this dictionary I can do this:

```
values_list = [dictionary_name['Key1']]
additional_values = [child['Key1'] for child in dictionary_name['Key2']]
values_list.extend(additional_values)
print(values_list)

Out: ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC']
```

Now consider if you didn't know how many descendants any Key2 might have. But you do know that any/all nodes will be formatted the same:

```
{
    "Key1":"value1",
    "Key2": [some or none child nodes]
}
```

So my question is: **Is there a way to build a list of all possible Key1 values?**

My current, messy attempt only get me to the second level.

```
values_list = []
for first_level in first_levels:
    values_list.append(first_level['Key1'])
    next_levels = first_level.get('Key2', [])
    next_levels_len = len(next_levels)
    while next_levels_len > 0:
        next_levels_len = 0
        for next_level in next_levels:
            values_list.append(next_level['Key1'])
            next_levels = next_level.get('Key2', [])
            next_levels_len += len(next_levels)
```

Comment: You probably want to write a recursive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple version:

```
def get_key1(d):
    vals = [d['Key1']]
    for subd in d['Key2']:
        vals += get_key1(subd)
    return vals
```

Then use it by doing `get_key1(my_dict)`.

The idea is that you want to put your logic into a function, and have that function call itself for each nested dictionary, then add the returned values to your list.

Answer (score 1):

A nice logical answer is given by [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172749/14867730) but for simple you can using `Regex-Expression` to extract out such pattern. Before using this please look at `string representation of dict-object`. For example:

```
>>>d = {"key1":"valueA"}
>>>str(d)
{'key1': 'valueA'}
```

So here few points to note:
**1.** Double Quotes(") is replace by Single Quotes (').
**2.** Space after colon.
Basically these are coding convention used in python but we ignore while coding.

```
dictionary_name ={
    "Key1":"valueA",
    "Key2": [
        {
            "Key1":"valueB",
            "Key2":[]
        },
        {
            "Key1":"valueC",
            "Key2":[]
        }
    ]
}

str_ = str(dictionary_name)
import re
regobt = re.compile(r"'Key1': '\w*'")
list_ = regobt.findall(str_)
print(list_)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
["'Key1': 'valueA'", "'Key1': 'valueB'", "'Key1': 'valueC'"]
```

#### Extracting Your Data from Output :

Extract your requirement from here by various method like again using `regular-expression` or just `string-indexing`.

Instead of doing thing use this extra code `.replace("'", '').replace(':','')` at
`str_` and update your regex object with this `re.compile(r"Key1 \w*")`.

**Now output will be :**

```
['Key1 valueA', 'Key1 valueB', 'Key1 valueC']
```

Comment: I really like this approach too

Comment: This is not really a robust way to do this.  It assumes that the Key1 value is made up of all word characters.  It also assumes that the keys and values are delimited by single quotes, which isn't guaranteed and will not (in current Python) be true if they contain any single quotes themselves.  Also, of course, it will be painful to generalize to even minor variations on the original problem, such as if the values can be tuples instead of lists, or if Key2 may be missing or have a single string value, etc.  Using the structure of dictionaries is better than relying on "stringly typed" data.

Comment: @BrenBarn I am 100% agree with you with your point of robustness but we can use `eval` to evaluate the type of data the value is. This is python everything is possible :)